# R aggregate function unexpected NA

Tags: r, aggregate

When I use aggregate function on a `data.frame` which contains character and numeric columns, aggregate fails and returns only NAs for all. How can I solve this? My first idea was to check for value class but it did not work.

```
name <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=2)
feat <- paste0("Feat",name)
valuesA <- runif(10)*10
valuesB <- runif(10)*10

daf <- data.frame(ID=name,feature=feat,valueA=valuesA,valueB=valuesB, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


 aggregate(.~ID, data=daf,FUN=mean)

 aggregate(.~ID, data=daf,FUN=function(x){
   if(is.character(x)){
     return(NA)
   }else{ return(mean(x))}
 })
```

Comment: `aggregate(.~ID, data=daf,FUN=mean)` works fine for me. It returns values and not `NA`.

Comment: In your example, `feature` is of class factor whereas in your actual problem it is character. The solution depends on what you want to do with your data. If you choose `mean` as the function, it cannot be calculated on `feature` so you get NAs (if feature is factor, like in your example here, that is treated as integer internally). So, this could work: `aggregate(.~ID, data=daf[-2],FUN=mean)`

Comment: Thanks, I see, the problem is why does the result of valueA and valueB depend on whether feature is factor or character ? If feature is of class factor, mean of valueA and value gets computed correctly. If feature is character everything is NA. Why ?